# Silverstripe, hide a page after specific date in the future

Tags: php, datepicker, content-management-system, admin, silverstripe

I want to have some kind of pages created with a certain expiration date (trying to apply a date picker from silverstripe documentation didn't work with me). 
That date should be in the future, at that date, I want to hide the article.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [silverstripe/advancedworkflow](http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/silverstripe/advancedworkflow) module - this supports Embargo/Expiry dates (among other things).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation using a CMS controlled ExpiryDate to control whether the page can be viewed or not. This solution is for Silverstripe 3.1.

```php
class Page extends SiteTree {

    private static $db = array(
        'ExpiryDate' => 'SS_Datetime'
    );

    public function canView($member = null) {
        if ($this->ExpiryDate) {
            if ($this->obj('ExpiryDate')->InPast()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return parent::canView($member);
    }

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $expiryDateField = Datetimefield::create('ExpiryDate', 'Page Expiry Date'), 'Content');
        $expiryDateField->getDateField()->setConfig('showcalendar', true);
        $expiryDateField->getTimeField()->setConfig('timeformat', 'HH:mm:ss');


        return $fields;
    }
}
```